# Mysql Error writing file /tmp/ Errcode 28 in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, my.cnf

Every time I try to select from my Mysql table with million plus rows in phpmyadmin I receive the following error:
"Error writing file /tmp/ Errcode 28"

Server Stats:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        30G   21G  7.5G  74% /
tmpfs           939M     0  939M   0% /dev/shm
/usr/tmpDSK     3.0G  176M  2.6G   7% /tmp
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=/tmp
innodb_file_per_table=1
open_files_limit=50000
myisam_use_mmap=1

max_connections = 200
max_user_connections = 75

join_buffer_size=2M
sort_buffer_size=2M

table_open_cache = 8000

table_definition_cache = 6000
max_allowed_packet = 1G

thread_cache_size = 384

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 100M
query_cache_limit = 1M

max_heap_table_size = 50M
tmp_table_size = 300M

key_buffer_size = 2500M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_autoextend_increment=64M
innodb_open_files=2000
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=mysql-slow.log
long_query_time=0.1
```

General Statistics --------------------------------------------------

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.35-cll
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 6G (Tables: 293)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 224K (Tables: 14)

[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 45

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 37m 24s (909 q [0.405 qps], 127 conn, TX: 608K, RX: 75K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 68% / 32%
[--] Total buffers: 5.6G global + 4.6M per thread (200 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.5G (356% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 4% (39/909)

[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 6% (13/200)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 2.4G/2.4G
[!!] Key buffer hit rate: 85.3% (685 cached / 101 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 47.4% (225 cached / 475 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 12 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 11% (2 on disk / 17 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 89% (13 created / 127 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 98% (379 open / 386 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (666/50K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 93%
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 224.0K/3.0G
```

How do I tune the server to manage such tables so the: "Error writing file /tmp/ Errcode 28" does not come up? I have several of such tables.

Thank you.

Comment: `perror 28` for me returns `OS error code  28:  No space left on device`, if it's the same for you...  (1) optimize queries so you _need_ less temporary table on the disk (2) if you've got ram to spare, up the limits in-memory tmp table can occupy until your tmp table fits (3) move your tmp dir to a bigger location, you can use any other dir then `/tmp`.